# Transferring code from MATLAB to C# - Curving Fitting

Tags: c#, matlab

I have the code to use [Curve Fitting Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/curvefitting.html) on MATLAB. For this plotting, I have 3 variables and I need to plot, with different curve fitting algorithms (i.e. Polynomial fit), a 3D graph that the user can interact at some level.

In C# I was able to code most of my mathematical formulas - pretty much transferring the ideas created in MATLAB to C#. The last part of this puzzle it is the curving fitting tool.

- I would like to know if there is any robust and reliable C# .net tool that I can use to plot graphs in 3D (similar to MATLAB?). I was able to find some help in https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/Fit.htm but it is only for X and Y - I need something for X, Y, and Z.

I don't expect the code! But some guidance would be helpful.

A few side notes:
1) We are migrating from MATLAB to C# because of the cost of MATLAB. Each toolbox cost so much money - they are amazing but expensive.
2) We cannot use OpenSource Tool - for some silly reason, they don't trust.

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Python might be a better option for plotting. But here is some documentation I found on c# 3D plotting https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14397/A-3D-Plotting-Library-in-C

Comment: @Flynn, I read that Python is robust for this! My problem is that the company uses C# as a standard - I cannot code in anything else.

Comment: That's too bad! Hopefully someone gives you a good answer!

Comment: The links provided in the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259873/what-free-library-may-i-use-for-creating-3d-surface-plot-graphic-in-c may help.

Comment: You can try to get some c++ code from curve-fitting tool using Matlab Coder (codegen function) and look through generated code for given input for better understanding?

Comment: @jodag , nice link! I will definitely try!